# Cocoapods missing project.pbxproj after Git clone

Tags: ios, swift, github, cocoapods

Im using cocoapods-0.36.0.beta.1 for a Swift IOS 8 project.

I keep code on a Git repo.

I got in a mess updating some libraries and decided to just clone down my project again.

I did the usual *pod install* after the clone. No complaints. Looked normal.

When i go to open the workspace I get

[image]

If i open the project i get

[image]

Has anyone any ideas on this as i'd love to get my project back? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have the original project you can show the .xcodeproj's packet content and copy the .pbxproj file. Than, paste it inside the cloned .xcodeproj's packet content.

Comment: What if you dont have the original